# Inno Setup - How to change background color of back/next/cancel buttons

Tags: inno-setup

I am able to change background colors of other controls as well as the WizardForm.
Is there any way to change the background color of these buttons?

Comment: There is, but it would be very difficult (subclassing the button control and painting everything by yourself). Much easier is using some ready made skinning plugin.

Comment: Thanks TLama. Could you please let me know where to get and how to use skinning plugin?

Comment: There are free ones, e.g. [this](http://isskin.codejock.com/), or [this](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins) and commercials ones, like [this](http://www.unsigned.sk/index.php/products/247-graphical-installer-inno-setup).

Comment: I agree with TLama's comment :) try the third mentioned (commercial): Graphical Installer for Inno Setup

Comment: It looks like the link was deleted: http://www.graphical-installer.com (a little self promo :)